# how to search without press enter

Tags: javascript, php, html

as the title say i have a text box and a table. i want the table update whenever i put any character in text box

my text box:

```
<form action="registration/popup_find" method="get">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="value">Search</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="value" id="value" placeholder="Search..." value="<?php echo $this->input->get('value'); ?>"> 
    </div></form>
```

my table :

```
 <table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>No Registrasi</th>
        <th>Tgl Registrasi</th>
        <th>Nama Pasien</th>
        <th>No Hospital</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $index = 0;
    foreach ($registration as $value) :
        echo Modules::run("registration/registration_table", $value, $index);
        $index++;
    endforeach;
    ?>
</table>
```

how to do that??

Comment: use javascript `onkeyup` event in your text box

Comment: $("#value").on('change', function() { //search statements });

Comment: @Paramore i forgot to mention, my text box located inside form

Comment: @yjs i forgot to mention, my text box located inside form

Comment: Wherever, it should work!

Comment: @yjs could you please add search statements too?

Comment: It is better to go for jquery plugin....and example is put up below. please check it. by Yatin

Answer (score 0):

You can use [data table](https://www.datatables.net/) a table plugin for jquery.

Its very easy to use and implement.

And if you are using bootsrap then you can use [this](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html)